# QUERY function with OR condition > Query Table, Select E where C contains Cell1 *OR* Cell2 limit 1

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I am attempting to use OR operator in the following Query.

The idea is that the cell will display mileage from a branch. The user can select a branch at either C12  or E12, and the cell will display the mileage from the table. My next move would be to make an if statement but I'm wondering if its possible to make it work like this

```
=iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, "Select E where C matches'"&C12&"' or C matches'"&E12&"'limit 1",0),"")`
```

What the current code does: Basically just runs this part

```
C matches'"&E12&"'limit 1",0),"")
```

But only when there is something in C12.

Any guidance appreciated

Update:
It *can* work with If and ISBLANK

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C16)=FALSE, iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, 
"Select E where C matches'"&C16&"' limit 1",0),""), 
iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, "Select E where C matches'"&E16&"' limit 1",0),""))
```

Copy of sheet to play with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fn5xzWi47xcgnQiDk5v_t1UDtIF6gHKGB4WoblbT3-Y/edit#gid=686684908

Comment: Please note that Excel does not have the `QUERY` function, thus I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(BranchesHrsKms, 
 "select E 
  where C matches '.*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*", 1, C12, E12)&".*' 
  limit 1", ))
```

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(C10:C23, BranchCodes!C:E, 3, ))+
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(E10:E23, BranchCodes!C:E, 3, ))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used TEXTJOIN like this before, but it queries the milage for the branch STAND when the selected branch was TA. STAND appears first in the table. Its acting more like `contains` where TA appears first in STAND. So far the best working solution is

`=IF(ISBLANK(C16)=FALSE, iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, 
"Select E where C matches'"&C16&"' limit 1",0),""), 
iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, "Select E where C matches'"&E16&"' limit 1",0),""))`

Comment: @MatthewRowlands can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Done :) i've now allowed the milage to be added. pretty clumsy code but seems to work fine.

Comment: @MatthewRowlands answer updated see the pink cell: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fn5xzWi47xcgnQiDk5v_t1UDtIF6gHKGB4WoblbT3-Y/edit#gid=772701566

Comment: Genius! I clearly have a lot to learn. I will keep the sheet for others to look through the process. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of space before `limit`

```
=iferror(query(BranchesHrsKms, "Select E where C contains '"&C12&"' or C contains '"&E12&"' limit 1",0),"")
```